# In standard Fortran grammar, can we specify some unused variant?

Tags: fortran

To find out all the (possible) problems that existed in the program, we had better turn on all the debug tools of the compiler. The tool will always tell us something like "remark #7712: This variable has not been used.".

In many cases, in order to keep some rules, I have to keep some input and output without using them. At the same time, I want to keep the debug tool turned on.

Can we do something by standard grammar to tell the compiler we really mean to do it and do not report any warning about it?

Comment: It is perfectly fine in standard Fortran to not use a variable. If you request this to issue a warning, it is your responsibility to interpret it or prevent it. Your compiler will have means to disable this kind of warning.

Comment: I don't really understand, but I expect you have some subroutine with a few arguments which are not used. What you could do is initialise all `INTENT(out)` which is generally also good practice. For the other options I do not see a solution unless you want to do a dummy operation with them. But even then some compilers could figure out that the operation is useless. Nonetheless, the comment from @VladimirF and the answer from @HighPerformanceMark answer your question best.

Comment: I, personally, use `-Wno-unused-dummy-argument -Wno-unused-variable` in gfortran. There is no standard solution, only compiler specific solutions, because it is a compiler specific warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fortran standard sets out the rules for correct programs and requires that compilers identify any breach of those rules.  Such breaches, which cause compilation to fail, are generally known as *errors*.

However, programmers make many mistakes which are not errors and which a (Fortran) compiler is not required to spot.  Some compilers provide additional diagnostic capabilities, such as identifying unused variables, which go beyond what the standard requires.  The compilers raise what are generally known as *warnings* in these cases.  This type of mistake does not cause compilation to fail.  Compilers also generally provide some means to determine which warnings are raised during compilation, so that you can switch off and on this diagnostic capability.  For details of these capabilities refer to your compiler's documentation.

The standard is entirely silent on this type of mistake so, if I understand the question correctly, there is nothing

> by standard grammar to tell the compiler we really mean to do it and
>   do not report any warning about it

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing (besides of course not declaring things you don't use)
may be to simply use the variables.

```
   real x
   x=huge(x) !reminder x is declared but not used.
```

at least makes gfortran happy that you have "used" the variable.

Comment: This, however, will influence the efficiency, even though not too much. But this makes me unhappy.